# How to do Asynchronous inserts in Aerospike using Python Client

Tags: aerospike

I am using Aerospike 3.4 and Python Clinet 1.0.41

I am able to achieve only around 1400 writes per second. This is by synchronous writes, single thread. Can anyone suggest how to improve the write speed on single thread. I didn't find Asynchronous write feature in Python client.

I have seen benchmark results on the web claiming around 8L writes per second on SSD.

My Configuration:
No of nodes:2,
CPUs: 16 per node,
Replication: 2,
Data Persistence: SSD

Thanks,
Dhanasekaran

Comment: Not sure if something like gevent would help here.

Comment: Those benchmarks normally use the Java client which is going to be much faster than the Python client. Also they probably used multiple clients. I'm not familiar with a benchmark doing 800k on a single node with SSD, could you provide a link to it? Were they PCIe SSDs?

Comment: All depends on your set up, really. I definitely clocked 12k/sec before. There are no async operations yet, but you should test with multi-process. In the real world you'd be in a server context or hopefully some other multi-process setting.

Comment: @kporter the below link has the bar chart at the end.  

http://lynnlangit.com/2015/01/28/lessons-learned-benchmarking-nosql-on-the-aws-cloud-aerospikedb-and-redis/

Comment: @Ronen 
I think Java client provides async writes.  It would be helpful to the community if the same feature be incorporated to Python Client.  Thanks.

Comment: We are in agreement here! Unfortunately there's no 'one way' to do it in Python, so it's being figured out still.

Comment: @carbonrock I think you missed the Title of the section with 800K tps (emphasis added) "Part 3a: Run Tests -> Benchmark Test 1 – Single node, **no persistence**". The prior section used persistence and was ~240K TPS.

Comment: @Ronen, Agreed. Thanks for your reply.  Figuring out other options to achieve this.

Comment: @kpoker, I didnt see 240K TPS anywhere. I am trying to achieve this using asynchronous calls using python client. A direct implementation is not possible because the feature not available in Python client as of now. Figuring out some other options to achieve this.

-- Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good news here is 'C' client 4.0 has been released with asynchronous support.  http://www.aerospike.com/download/client/c/notes.html.

Since python client wraps around C client, there are very good chances that python client will have this feature sooner.

Comment: @Ronen can you please throw some light on it?

Comment: The client is now asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Updated 2015-07-29:

(1) The Python Aerospike client is fully synchronous at the moment. There appeared to be no firm plans for async support in the discussion at https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/gevent-compatibility-or-async-api/1001 
 but Ronen has since confirmed below (see comments) that async support is planned for all clients in the future.

(2) Regarding 1.4k TPS, I experienced very similar results when hosting Aerospike in a VirtualBox VM and connecting from the physical host. This may be due to VirtualBox's networking issues. When the client (Java benchmark) was run on the same VM as the host database, my speed went up to about 8k TPS.

Comment: As the person to last comment on that thread I'd like to reiterate that we definitely DO plan to have async support in all clients. It is currently present in the ones for Java, C#, Go, libevent. As the Python client wraps around the C client, which doesn't have support, this is a deferred matter. However, it's being prototyped.

Comment: One further comment, on my _laptop_ writing to a _vm_ I get to the neighborhood of 12K TPS/sec with an 80/20 split on reads and writes. Python, PHP, node.js, etc benefit from a multiprocessing model. The simple performance script in the PHP client spins off multiple processes as it runs the test. This is standard for clients that don't have real threads (employ a GIL) as Python, PHP, Ruby, and node.js do.

Comment: @Ronen IMO the tone of the referenced thread was "we're discussing it as a possibility, but you can always do it yourself as it's open source"--i.e. there was no indication of firm plans. But to hear you confirm it here is good news.

Answer (score -1):

Source code: https://github.com/sean-tan-columbia/aerospike-async-client

I've implemented an Aerospike asynchronous client as an open-source project, the source code is as above. It has been tested on Aerospike 3.3 with Aerospike Python Client 1.0.38 and Python 2.7.

I just recently started it so it's not yet mature, welcome to improve it!